# Google Cloud Run: how to store temporary files with Python?

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-run

I tried to use the open command, e.g.

```
with open("fname.txt") as f:
    f.write("example")
```

But once I deploy the container, I don't know where this file is stored, or how to get its content back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use full path instead `/tmp/<file>`